# LINQ: Get Table Column Names

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Using LINQ, how can I get the column names of a table? C# 3.0, 3.5 framework

Comment: Retagged to `linq-to-sql`, please edit your question if you meant some other kind of "LINQ".

Comment: Unfortunately this query run inside LINQPad so how do I get the context in LINQPad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean by using LINQ to SQL, in which case look at the [DataContext.Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.mapping.aspx) property. That's what I use.

If you don't mean that, perhaps you can elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to write a program using LINQPad (C#) That can build SQL insert statements off course for this I require the column names of the tables.

Comment: could this be clarified a bit...this is not much of an answer.

Comment: Some example usage would be great.  The Mapping API is a bit un-intuitive to say the least...

Answer (score 23):

Maybe It is too late but, I solved this problem by this code

```
var db = new DataContex();
var columnNames = db.Mapping.MappingSource
                      .GetModel(typeof(DataContex))
                      .GetMetaType(typeof(_tablename))
                      .DataMembers;
```

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me a boat load of time.  This is better than the accepted answer because this shows how to use the DataContext.Mapping property.

Comment: For VB.Net use `GetType(DataContext)` instead of `typeof(DataContext)`.

Answer (score 15):

The below code will worked from returns all the column names of the table

```
var columnnames = from t in typeof(table_name).GetProperties() select t.Name
```

Comment: Not sure why this was not upvoted, it is the most elegant answer. Here is the lambda syntax equivalent: var columnnames = typeof(table_name).GetProperties().Select(t => t.Name);

Comment: Maybe this wasn't upvoted as you don't only get the columns but additional properties as well. It's usually a partial class with extensibility in mind after all.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon this question looking for the same thing and didn't see a really good answer here.  This is what I came up with.  Just throw it into LINQPad under C# expression mode.

```
from t in typeof(UserQuery).GetProperties()
where t.Name == "Customers"
from c in t.GetValue(this,null).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetFields()
select c.Name
```

Modify as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ExecuteQuery method on your data context and execute this SQL script:

```
var columnNames = ctx.ExecuteQuery<string>
    ("SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('your table name');");
```

This gives you an `IEnumerable<string>` with all the column names in that table you specified.

Of course, if you want and need to, you could always retrieve more information (e.g. data type, max length) from the `sys.columns` catalog view in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

I used this code in LinqPad

```
from t in typeof(table_name).GetFields() select t.Name
```

Comment: Note that it is the unpluralized version of the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the properties of your L2S classes with reflection

Answer (score 0):

```
            var query = from x in DataBase.Table_Name
                        select x.Column_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

sp_help 'TableName'

An option for a LinqPad SQL window to ms sql server

Answer (score 0):

In LinqPad:

TableNames.Take(1) works.

It is fast to type. (Although you in an ideal world, it would be nicer to not select any rows.)

Note it is the pluralized form of TableName. You can also do Take(0) and look at the SQL results tab.

Answer (score -1):

I am using .net core 3.0 and none of these solutions worked for me.  My solution was a brute forced approach using Newtonsoft Json serializer.

```
var dt = this._context.Prodmats.First();  // get the first row of my table

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);  
 
var tva2 = new string(json.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsDigit(c) || c == ':' 
                        || c == ',' || char.IsWhiteSpace(c) ).ToArray())  ;

        var  arr = tva2.Split(',');

        var col = new List<string>();

        foreach (var val in arr)
        { 
          var ch = val.Split(':');
           
          var trimCh = ch[0];               
          col.Add(trimCh.Trim());
        }
```

// col <= has the columns list

Comment: This gives property names, not table column names. Also, the question is not about EF, already has many answers, and there are similar questions that are about EF.