# How to get column names for a linq sql query result in vb 2010

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I've seen C# examples but can not find a way to get the column names from the results of a LINQ SQL query in VISUAL BASIC.

So myLINQ query looks like this:

```
Dim dbs As New DataClasses1DataContext
Dim s As Table(Of sched) = dbs.GetTable(Of sched)()
Dim sQuery = From sp In s
Where sp.custID = cID
Select sp Order By sp.scheddate
```

There are 13 fields in the table sched, and I'd like to be able to read off the column names in a foreach type loop. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Extrapolating from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803192/linq-get-table-column-names) I'd think something like `var columnNames = dbs.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(GetType(DataClasses1DataContext))                      .GetMetaType(GetType(sched)).DataMembers`

Comment: Why do you need column names? What are you doing with the data once selected?

Comment: I am populating a datagrid using code like: Dim MyTable As New DataTable
        Dim dc As DataColumn

        For Each r In schedNames
            dc = New DataColumn
            dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
            dc.ColumnName = "SID"
            MyTable.Columns.Add(dc)
        Next

Comment: So Stuartd answered the question. I just needed to tweak for VB slightly: Dim columnNames = dbs.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(GetType(DataClasses1DataContext)).GetMetaType(GetType(sched)).DataMembers  THANKS.