# Get all column names of a DataClass into string array using (LINQ)

Tags: vb.net, reflection, linq-to-sql

I want to get all the table headers of my Data Class from my Data Context (named dc).
[image]

I tried a lot of different things:
[image]
[image]
[image]

And so on.

I went through a lot of different (stackoverflow) pages, but I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate: [LINQ: Get Table Column Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803192/linq-get-table-column-names)

Comment: Like I mentioned: I tried these, and I can't get it to work, see the options that I tried above, with the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by this code:
So my GetType DataContext, should have been ProductionDataContext, since I renamed it to that.  I was confused by the errors that VS gave, and didn't look further anymore.

```
Dim dc As New ProductionDataContext
Dim columnNames = dc.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(GetType(ProductionDataContext)).GetMetaType(GetType(tblInterventies)).DataMembers
```